# Trigger code on page load into DOM

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

This should be so easy, but I can't seem to figure it out.

How do I trigger code on a page-load into the DOM (not page-init) in JQuery Mobile?

I'm trying this code, but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainerbeforeload", "#my-page-id", function(event, data) {
   console.log("page load");
});
```

Using JQuery Mobile 1.4.4 and JQuery 2.1.1

Here's a Fiddle that shows what I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/wpgs06r1/2/

Comment: Page container load events are triggered when you load an external page (url) http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/05/23/jquery-mobile-page-events-extra/ demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/2SCbL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of $(document) as the selector, the pagecontainer widget is in the body, so try:

```
$( "body" ).on( "pagecontainerbeforeshow", function( event, ui ) {} );
```

You can also use the jQM selector, :mobile-pagecontainer instead of body:

```
$( ":mobile-pagecontainer" )
```